# Uniqueness of distributional solutions to the Poisson equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, schwartz-distributions

Let $S(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the space of all [Schwartz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) on $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the topology induced by the usual Schwartz semi-norms. Let $S(\mathbb R^n)^*$ denote its dual.

**My question.** Suppose that $A, B\in S(\mathbb R^n)^*$ both satisfy the same [Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation), which in essence means that, in the weak sense,
$$\Delta A=\Delta B,$$
where $\Delta$ is the (weak) [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian). Can we conclude that $A=B$ ?

---

*My idea.* Just following the definitions, we see that $\Delta A=\Delta B$ means that $\langle A,\Delta \phi\rangle = \langle B, \Delta\phi\rangle$ for all test functions $\phi\in S(\mathbb R^n)$. Can we conclude that $\langle A,\tilde\phi\rangle = \langle B, \tilde\phi\rangle$ for all test functions $\tilde\phi\in S(\mathbb R^n)$ ? I am asking because there exist $\tilde\phi\in S(\mathbb R^n)$ for which there is no $\phi\in S(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $$\Delta \phi=\tilde\phi.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can conclude that $A - B$ is a harmonic polynomial: If you take the Fourier transform, you see that $|\xi|^2 (\hat{A} - \hat{B}) = 0$, so $\hat{A} - \hat{B}$ is supported at the origin. (All of this makes sense at the level of tempered distributions.) Therefore, $A - B$ is a polynomial. (This required the classification of distributions supported at a single point -- see Hormander, Vol. 1.)

If you know beforehand that, say, $A - B \in L^2$, then you can conclude that $A = B$.

-Dallas

Comment: So for general $A,B$ we can't always conclude $A=B$ ?  PS: I hope your French is doing well .

Comment: Right, it just isn't true at that level of generality. ($A$ and $B$ could be different constants.) But at least you know what their difference must be. And thank you :)

Comment: Yes @MaximilianJanisch, you cannot always conclude that $A=B$, and this is in general true for every linear partial differential operator: the non homogeneous equation has a solution which is unique modulo a solution of the homogeneous equation. To make sure that this is only the null one, you must assume additional requirements as sharpened has exemplified.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Ohhh right, since $A-B$ could be any weak solution to the Laplace equation. Took me a while to see ! Thanks to both of you!

Comment: There is no polynomial, except 0, in the space $S(R^n)$, if I correctly understand that $S(R^n)$ is the space of Schwartz test functions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes absolutely, but $A-B$ can be of the type $A-B: S(\mathbb R^n)\to\mathbb R, \phi\mapsto\int_{\mathbb R^n} p\phi\,\mathrm dx$ for a polynomial $p$. I am pretty sure that that is what Dallas meant 